# Should I return an Entity from a POST in all cases?

Tags: rest, architecture, post

As I understand, the RESTful [convention](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.5) is for POSTs creating a resource to return the full or annotated created entity, however it's been my experience that this entity is usually discarded unless the service itself or the client is being tested.

I'm not a slave to REST when creating public facing APIs especially when I deem that for usability or architectural reasons it doesn't make sense, but one thing I've always wondered about and never done is returning `204 No Content` from POSTs creating new entities (especially ones that are large in size). This can cut down on bandwidth for users making a lot of requests and make responses on my end faster.

Is this an acceptable practice or does it make you die a little inside? Note that I wouldn't consider this without providing an endpoint to retrieve this entity for testing reasons.

EDIT: I'm looking for anecdotal observations or concrete examples of why this particular use case might be harmful, even if it was well documented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The document you linked to has the answer to the question you are askign:

> If a resource has been created on the origin server, the response
>   SHOULD be 201 (Created) and contain an entity which describes the
>   status of the request and refers to the new resource, and a Location
>   header (see section 14.30).
>
> Responses to this method are not cacheable, unless the response
>   includes appropriate Cache-Control or Expires header fields. However,
>   the 303 (See Other) response can be used to direct the user agent to
>   retrieve a cacheable resource.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm quite familiar with REST and I also don't think it needs to be followed word for word. I guess I'm looking for anecdotal observations about this specific use case and if people use the returned entities. I'll edit to be more clear

Comment: Here's what confuses me.  You are claiming a convention, but the link  is to a document establishing a standard, not a usage convention of that standard.  Maybe it's just my ignorance showing, but why do you claim that there is a convention in returning full entities?  Do you have a citation for that?

Comment: Semantically speaking I'm using "convention" and "standard" in the same sense, as in: "This is the RESTful way to do a POST". I'm not really concerned about the wording. The citation is the link that you and I both referred to. As my question states, there are countless examples where people knowingly don't obey REST to a "T" based on countless different use cases. This latter part is what I'm interested in, in regards to my question.

Comment: ReST is an architectural principle. HTTP is a transfer protocol that may be used in adherence with ReST. HTTP defines 200, 201, 204, and 303 as valid responses to a POST request depending on what is returned. So if your question is about HTTP, I don't see what is being disobeyed by returning 204.

However, if the question is in whether returning a 204 response is RESTful, then it's a different matter (though, then I don't understand why you are citing an HTTP spec instead of the REST-related source). Regardless, I don't see how RESTful principles are being violated here either.

Comment: This isn't a question about what's technically feasible. I'm not asking whether or not I can or cannot implement this. Please re-read the question.

Comment: As for HTTP vs. REST: REST "conforms to the uniform interface constraint" i.e. it "SHOULD" comply whenever possible. The should is what I'm asking about.

Comment: Where do I talk about the technical feasibility?  I'm just addressing what the HTTP spec and REST principles say.  And what I am saying is that I don't see how returning 204 would break either the HTTP spec or the REST principles.  So I don't understand the nature of your question.  As far as I can tell it's based on an invalid assumption that one must "return the full or annotated created entity." There is no such requirement.

Answer (score 5):

Regarding the use of `204 No Content`, according to the spec, you would return this (or `200`) when the `POST` creates a resource that is not identified by a URI.  If this correctly describes your use case, then a `204` would be appropriate.

As @Dmitry refers to in his comment, the returned entity does not necessarily have to be the new resource.  For example, if the resource's ID is assigned by the server, the response could be an entity containing only that server generated ID.

A concrete example of this is shown in the CouchDB [documentation for POST](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API#POST).

For this sample request:

```
POST /somedatabase/ HTTP/1.0
Content-Length: 245
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "Subject":"I like Plankton",
  "Author":"Rusty",
  "PostedDate":"2006-08-15T17:30:12-04:00",
  "Tags":["plankton", "baseball", "decisions"],
  "Body":"I decided today that I don't like baseball. I like plankton."
}
```

the server response would be an entity containing the status, ID, and revision:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Date: Thu, 17 Aug 2006 05:39:28 +0000GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Connection: close

{"ok":true, "id":"123BAC", "rev":"946B7D1C"}
```